# Issue with running multiple cplex models in parallel using multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, cplex, docplex

I want to solve multiple cplex models simultaneously using python multiprocessing. I understand that the basic example of multiprocessing in python is something like:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

def func1():

 '''some code'''

def func2():

'''some code'''

if __name__=='__main__':
    p1 = Process(target = func1)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target = func2)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

The structure of my script is like:

```
Model1(args**):
'''cplex model written with docplex'''
return model

Model2(args**):
'''cplex model written with docplex'''
return model

Generate_pool1(args**):
    cpx = mdl.get_cplex()
    cpx.parameters.parallel.set(1)
    cpx.parameters.threads.set(5)
    cpx.parameters.emphasis.mip.set(4)
    cpx.parameters.simplex.tolerances.markowitz.set(0.999)
    cpx.parameters.simplex.tolerances.optimality.set(1e-9)
    cpx.parameters.simplex.tolerances.feasibility.set(1e-9)
    cpx.parameters.mip.pool.intensity.set(4)
    cpx.parameters.mip.pool.absgap.set(1e75)
    cpx.parameters.mip.pool.relgap.set(1e75)
    cpx.populatelim=50
    
    numsol = cpx.solution.pool.get_num()
    return numsol


Generate_pool2(args**):
    cpx = mdl.get_cplex()
    cpx.parameters.parallel.set(1)
    cpx.parameters.threads.set(5)
    cpx.parameters.emphasis.mip.set(4)
    cpx.parameters.simplex.tolerances.markowitz.set(0.999)
    cpx.parameters.simplex.tolerances.optimality.set(1e-9)
    cpx.parameters.simplex.tolerances.feasibility.set(1e-9)
    cpx.parameters.mip.pool.intensity.set(4)
    cpx.parameters.mip.pool.absgap.set(1e75)
    cpx.parameters.mip.pool.relgap.set(1e75)
    cpx.populatelim=50
    
    numsol = cpx.solution.pool.get_num()
    return numsol

main():
 for i in range(len(data)-1):
    m1=Model1(data[i])
    m2=Model2(data[i+1])
    p1 = Process(target = Generate_pool1,(m1,i),)
    p1.start()
    p2 = Process(target = Generate_pool2,(m2,i+1),)
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

When I run this code the cplex part doesn't work. The console keeps running but nothing happens and the process does not finish by itself, I have to keyboard interrupt it everytime. My engine has 32 virtual cores and it's runnig on spyder -windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

with docplex you may find an example in https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/

https://github.com/PhilippeCouronne/docplex_contribs/blob/master/docplex_contribs/src/zoomontecarlo2.py

which uses

https://github.com/PhilippeCouronne/docplex_contribs/blob/master/docplex_contribs/src/process_pool.py

that relies on

import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

This example relies on [docplex](https://pypi.org/project/docplex/)

Comment: Thank you Alex. I still don't understand how to relate these to my main issue and my code